# Как сделать такой эффект?

Tags: xml, android-sdk, android, java

[image: лучший сайт в мире]

Вот как на верхней картине, как сделать такую тень в XML?

Comment: Я такое как-то делал с помощью кастомной вьюхи. Делал массив слоёв с GradientDrawable и устанавливал как Background.

Comment: Думаю, вы можете найти решение там же, откуда эта картинка: 
https://developer.android.com/training/material/shadows-clipping.html

Answer (score 4):

```
android:elevation="2dp"
```

Чем больше число - тем выше объект, соотвественно больше тень.

Работает на Android 5.0 и выше. На раних версиях отображается без тени.